# Get a list of users from AD where Username is like a given value

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I was wondering if there was a way to find a User in Active Directory that is LIKE what a user has typed and then post it back to a previous page within the application.

I have the following code

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{               
    UserPrincipal queryAdUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    queryAdUser.SamAccountName = "Thomas";
    using (PrincipalSearcher searchAdUser = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
    {
        foreach (UserPrincipal UsersFound in searchAdUser.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry res = UsersFound.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Response.Write(res.Properties["givenName"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This currently only returns the user that matches the entered value by the user. So lets say I entered a search of "T" and I had in Active Directory "Tom, Ted and Tim" I want to return these users as results when the user searches.

Is it possable to alter the above code to perform this task, or this there a better way that I could be doing this?

Kind Regards

Comment: You can add wildcards (asterisks) around the account name: `queryAdUser.SamAccountName = "*T*"`. That would return all accounts with a T in it. Or you can just have a trailing wildcard to find all accounts that start with a T. Whatever, you know how wildcards work.

Comment: See the duplicate mentioned - it has an answer - basically, you need to use `queryAdUser.SamAccountName = "T*";`